# Cannot install ownCloud on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 16.04, dependencies, owncloud-client

I get the following errors while trying to install ownCloud:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  owncloud : Depends:
owncloud-server (= 8.1.8-12.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: mysql-server but it is not installable or
                        mariadb-server but it is not installable
            Recommends: exim4 but it is not installable or
                        mail-transport-agent but it is not installable
            Recommends: owncloud-config-apache (= 8.1.8-12.1) but it is not 
going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you haveheld broken packages.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What command did you give to install own-cloud?

Comment: The latest version of owncloud for Ubuntu 16.04 is 9.1.  I assume that you have a older version of Ubuntu which you now upgraded. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of Owncloud called `Nextcloud`, and it is the version that is better supported. I recommend to use `Nextcloud` instead.

In Ubuntu 16.04 you can install Nextcloud as a snap (the new type of installation packages for Ubuntu 16.04 or newer).

The full documentation on how to try the snap edition of Nextcloud can be found at
https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get autoclean --purge
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get ugrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hopefully now the dependency problem will get resolved

Now to install owncloud type in terminal

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud
```

To install owncloud files type in terminal

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud-files
```

**NOTE**: This will only work in **Ubuntu 16.04**

For **Ubuntu 15.10**

To install owncloud type in terminal

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_15.10/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_15.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud
```

To install owncloud files type:

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_15.10/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_15.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud-files
```

For **Ubuntu 14.04**

To install owncloud type

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_14.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud
```

To install owncloud-files type:

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_14.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud-files
```

In **Ubuntu 12.04**

To install owncloud type

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_12.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_12.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud
```

To install owncloud-files type

```
wget -nv https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_12.04/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Ubuntu_12.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
apt-get update
apt-get install owncloud-files
```

Comment: I removed the 'find / -name "*owncloud*" -exec rm -rf {} \;' command from this reply. Apart from the obvious that it may remove irrelevant files from the whole filesystem, it may also damage the package management by removing important files that happened to have `owncloud` in their name. Also, please use 'sudo' for the commands that require root privileges.